# Consuming json in localhost without postman

Tags: java, json, spring

How or can we consume a JSON in localhost without postman?

The post code:

```
@PostMapping(value = STATISTICS_URL + "/age", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity getStudentsBetweenAge(@RequestBody AgeDto ageDto) {
    if (null == ageDto.getMaxAge()) {
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(studentService.findByAgeGreaterThanOrEqual(ageDto.getMinAge()));
    }
    return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(studentService.findByAgeBetween(ageDto));
}
```

Postman -->

[image: Postman]

For localhost in browser how can I consume a JSON here: ---->

[image]

I'm kinda new with spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers doesn't perform a POST request. You need to either use a command line tool like [curl](https://curl.haxx.se), or set up a minimum webpage with ajax requests in order to perform a post to your service.